# Shapeless: Mapping an natural transformation over a KList

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless, context-bound

Is there a way to map a natural transformation (e.g. a `Option ~> Either[String, *]`) over a KList (e.g. a `HList` with a `UnaryTCConstraint`)? That would seem to be the natural thing to do with a KList.

Specifically I was trying to do the following:

```scala
object myNaturalTransformation extends (Option ~> Either[String, *]) {
  def apply[T](a: Option[T]): Either[String, T] = a.toRight("oh noe!")
}

def doStuff[KList <: HList: *->*[Option]#λ](klist: KList) = {
  klist.map(myNaturalTransformation)
}
```

I understand that the missing piece is the `Mapper` required to perform the `.map` and that Shapeless isn't able to generate one from `myNaturalTransformation`s cases and the `UnaryTCConstraint`. Is it possible to obtain one some other way? Or is there another approach to map over a KList that I'm overlooking (apart from passing a `Mapper` to the `doStuff`-function)?

I was able to write my own version of `UnaryTCConstraint` that includes a

```scala
def mapper[G[_], HF <: ~>[TC, G]](hf: HF): Mapper[hf.type, L]
```

to explicitly generate a mapper for a given natural transformation. However I am curious if it's possible to do that with Shapeless' implementation of `UnaryTCConstraint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UnaryTCConstraint` (`*->*`) is not for mapping, it's a constraint (common for `HList`s, `Coproduct`s, case classes and sealed traits). For mapping there are type classes `NatTRel`, `Mapped`, `Comapped`, `Mapper` etc. (separate for `HList`s and `Coproduct`s).

Try both constraint and type class

```
def doStuff[KList <: HList: *->*[Option]#λ, L <: HList](klist: KList)(implicit 
  natTRel: NatTRel[KList, Option, L, Either[String, *]]
): L = natTRel.map(myNaturalTransformation, klist)
```

or just type class

```
def doStuff[KList <: HList, L <: HList](klist: KList)(implicit 
  natTRel: NatTRel[KList, Option, L, Either[String, *]]
): L = natTRel.map(myNaturalTransformation, klist)
```

or hiding type parameter `L` via `PartiallyApplied` pattern

```
def doStuff[KList <: HList] = new PartiallyAppliedDoStuff[KList]

class PartiallyAppliedDoStuff[KList <: HList] {
  def apply[L <: HList](klist: KList)(implicit 
    natTRel: NatTRel[KList, Option, L, Either[String, *]]
  ): L = natTRel.map(myNaturalTransformation, klist)
}
```

or hiding type parameter `L` via existential (but then return type is not precise)

```
def doStuff[KList <: HList](klist: KList)(implicit 
  natTRel: NatTRel[KList, Option, _, Either[String, *]]
) = natTRel.map(myNaturalTransformation, klist)
```

or using extension method

```
implicit class NatTRelOps[KList <: HList](val klist: KList) extends AnyVal {
  def map[F[_], G[_], L <: HList](f: F ~> G)(implicit 
    natTRel: NatTRel[KList, F, L, G]
  ): L = natTRel.map(f, klist)
} 

def doStuff[KList <: HList, L <: HList](klist: KList)(implicit 
  natTRel: NatTRel[KList, Option, L, Either[String, *]]
): L = klist.map(myNaturalTransformation)
```

Testing:

```
doStuff(Option(1) :: Option("a") :: HNil)           // compiles
//doStuff(Option(1) :: Option("a") :: true :: HNil) // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Are there any resources to learn about Shapeless constraints? If UnaryTCConstraint is not for mapping, what is is's purpose?
Also I could only find constraints for HLists in Shapeless 2.3.3, ant not also for Coproducts, case classes and sealed traits as you metioned.

Comment: @mrArkwright Well, Shapeless documentation is not perfect. There are a [book](https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/), [wiki](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0), [examples](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples) and [tests](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/tree/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless). For example tests for [constraints](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/constraints.scala).

Comment: @mrArkwright If you look at `UnaryTCConstraint` [sources](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/constraints.scala), it's pretty obvious that it's a type class such that for a type `A` either there is an instance `UnaryTCConstraint[A]` or not. `*->*` is for a context bound. There are no type members or methods in the type class. So there is no way to transform the type `A` into some `B` or a value `a: A` into some `b: B`. And there defined instances for `HNil`, `CNil`, `H :: T`, `H :+: T`, and with `Generic`.

Comment: @mrArkwright Its purpose is being a constraint, not mapping. I.e. verifying that a type parameter `L` of a method or type class is of form `TC[A] :: TC[B] :: ... :: HNil` or `TC[A] :+: TC[B] :+: ... :+: CNil` or `SomeCaseClass(tca: TC[A], tcb: TC[B], ...)`.

Comment: Up until 2.3.3 `UnaryTCConstraint` seems to be limited to `HList`. From 2.4.0-M1 on it works on `Coproduct` and `Generic` as well. So that explains my confusion about that.

Comment: I've read through all of these resources. I'm still not clear about what can be achieved with a `UnaryTCConstraint`. Maybe I should have phrased my question differently: What is the purpose of a constraint, in which scenarios can it be applied and what can be achieved by them? Only restricting a function call to a certain property but then not being able to do anything with that information seems counterintuitive. Or is that exactly what constraints in Shapeless achieve?

Comment: @mrArkwright You're right about versions. I haven't noticed. https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/shapeless-2.3.3/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hlistconstraints.scala Regarding use cases you can search for `UnaryTCConstraint` https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UnaryTCConstraint

Comment: @mrArkwright *"but then not being able to do anything with that information seems counterintuitive."* Well, I guess you can do something, just not with the type class (or with another type class). Let's say can it be useful to check that all fields of a class are optional?

Comment: @mrArkwright Not all operations are type-level (that can be done at compile-time). There are many operations that can be done only at runtime.